# How to remove zero in front of string and cast in number in java

Tags: java, string, long-integer

I have string `0000001.45` and I want to remove zero in front of the string and convert string to long. Is it possible to cast without loops. Have java some function for this.

Comment: So what have you tried already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the first thing that comes to mind:

```
 long result=(long)Double.parseDouble("000001.45");
```

The Double class can parse away the leading zeros, and the cast will convert to long.

Comment: ... which is "1" but, hey, that was the objective ;-)

Comment: Indeed. I don't know what the goal was - if it was to normalize it to 145, well, obviously other things would be done.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the [Long.parseLong()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29) or equivalent classes for all the different Number types. I think you will need to parse it has a float or double then convert it to a long type.

Comment: Crash. Boom. Bang. (the input has a small, ugly dot) - but as you didn't suggest to use *that* method on the input - no downvote from my side ;)